# How to save even numbers in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I tried to keep even numbers by removing the odd but there seams to be a problem.

```
keepeven([], []).
keepeven([X|Xs], Even) :- 0 is X mod 2, keepeven(Xs, [Even|X]).
```

And I tried:

```
keepeven([], []).
keepeven([X|Xs], [X|Even]) :- 0 is X mod 2, keepeven(Xs, Even).
```

I'm missing something. :/

I should get from

```
keepeven([1,2,3,4,5], Even).
Even = [2,4].
```

But I just get fail.

Comment: What if an odd element is in the list, then eventually `X` will be that odd element, how is Prolog to proceed here?

Comment: You should search this site for `[prolog] filter list`. There are numerous answers giving a variety of perspectives on the more general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm missing something. :/

Yes, you are missing the case where the number is *odd*, since in that case `0 is X mod 2` will fail, but Prolog can not backtrack to another clause that "removes" that element.

We can for example add an extra clause:

```
keepeven([], []).
keepeven([X|Xs], [X|Even]) :- 0 is X mod 2, keepeven(Xs, Even).
keepeven([X|Xs], Even) :- 1 is X mod 2, keepeven(Xs, Even).
```

or use an if-then-else clause:

```
keepeven([], []).
keepeven([X|Xs], R) :-
    (  0 is X mod 2
    -> R = [X|Even]
    ;  R = Even),
    keepeven(Xs, Even).
```

Comment: Glob freaking damn it. Thx Willem